# How can I weight each MongoDB search query differently?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-performance, database

I have a MongoDB collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "McAllister's Deli",
    "menu": [
        {"sandwich": 4},
        {"spud": 3},
        {"salad": 5},
        {"cookie":2}
    ],
    "reviews": 45
}
```

I would like to rank these restaurants based on the types of food they have and the number of reviews. For instance, if someone is looking for `cookie` and `sandwich`, `McAllister's Deli` would return a ranking of say  `19.28` by taking `(cookie * sandwich * reviews) / menuItems`. Is there a way to optimize my query to take this ranking into account?

Edit: Since it was asked in a comment, I am currently using the Dart driver, but I am familiar with the Mongo shell and can translate a shell query to a query my driver understands.

Comment: Are you doing this through the mongo shell?  If not, which driver?

Comment: I'm using the Dart driver, but I'm willing to move to any really, but I've used the Python driver in the past. That being said, if you know how to do it from the shell, I can look at how I would implement the query using the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.rest.aggregate([{
    $project: { 
        _id: 1,
        sandwich: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$menu.sandwich', 0]},
        cookie: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$menu.cookie', 0]},
        menuItems: {$size: '$menu'}
    }
},{
    $project: { 
        _id: 1,
        rank: { $divide: [{ $add: ['$sandwich', '$cookie']}, '$menuItems' ]}
    }
}
```

])

probably can be combined. $project is separated for clearance.